# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'3\n1\n\n'

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with my code I have a TCP connection where i'm the client and I'm receiving numbers like:

```
1
4
6
3
..
```

(the numbers I receive are only: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) in a random order.
The error I'm getting is: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'2\n6\n\n'.

the piece of code referring to this part is:

```
# TCP connection
try:
    so = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error as err:
    print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

# default port for socket
port = 2000

# default time out
so.settimeout(1000000)

try:
    host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
except socket.gaierror:
    # this means could not resolve the host
    print ("there was an error resolving the host")
    sys.exit()

# connecting to the server
so.connect((host_ip,port))

# MATLAB INFORMATION FOR OFFLINE EXPERIMENT
Nepoch = 10  #nr de epochs por trial
Nwords = 7   #nr de palavras (SIM, NAO, FOME, SEDE, URINAR, AR, POSICAO)
SeqTrain = [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6] #sequencia offline de treino

# read the TCP sequence received
def sequencia():
    num = 0
    for i in range(0,999):
        s = so.recv(port) + b'\n' #since the sequence received is : 1\n 2\n 5\n etc
        i = int(s)
        #feedbak offline (for the user to know which are the words)
        if (num in (0, Nepoch*Nwords+1, Nepoch*Nwords*2+2, Nepoch*Nwords*3+3, Nepoch*Nwords*4+4, Nepoch*Nwords*5+5,\
                    Nepoch*Nwords*6+6)):
            labels1[i-1].configure(foreground="white")
            root.update()
        elif (num in (Nepoch*Nwords*7+7, Nepoch*Nwords*8+8, Nepoch*Nwords*9+9, Nepoch*Nwords*10+10,\
                     Nepoch*Nwords*11+11, Nepoch*Nwords*12+12, Nepoch*Nwords*13+13)):
            labels2[i-1].configure(foreground="white")
            root.update()
        else:
            labels[i-1].configure(background="green",foreground="red")
            root.update()
            winsound.PlaySound(sounds[i-1], winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            labels[i-1].configure(background="gray",foreground="white")
            root.update()
        num = num + 1
```

where the error is in the part : line 44:  i = int(s).
Do you have any ideas how I can solve this? Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `s` just before the line 44?

Comment: yes, it is like this: b'1\n\n'
b'7\n\n'
b'4\n\n'
b'2\n\n'
b'6\n\n'
b'3\n\n'
b'1\n\n'
b'5\n\n'

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
so.recv(port)
```

You're receiving more than one number as a response. Try:

```
s = so.recv(port)
for i in [int(n) for n in s.split(b'\n') if n]:
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i tried but it still doesnh't work. The error now is: 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'2\n6\n' '

Comment: what do you see if you do `print(repr(s))`?

Comment: the printed values of s are like this:  b'1\n\n' b'7\n\n' b'4\n\n' b'2\n\n' b'6\n\n' b'3\n\n' b'1\n\n' b'5\n\n'

Comment: What about `print(type(s))`?

Comment: all bytes: <class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'> (...)

Comment: I don't if this helps to help me, but the program works for the first 2/3 numbers and then stops and appears that error.

Comment: Sorry - I'm out of ideas. My code works for all the values you've shown me, including the value from your traceback, so I can't tell why it's not working for you.